# How to configure quick class or method definition navigation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often need to enter a class or method definition when I move my mouse cursor to it. I don't like "Ctr+B" to go into the definition. How to configure it to make me "double click" the class or method name to enter the definition, or at lease make it a button to appear on the main tool bar?

Comment: File | Settings | Keymap

Comment: @meo, can you please make a full answer, to achieve the 'double click' effect?

Comment: Open Keymap, find Ctr+B action, assign double-click.

Comment: In Keymap, where to click further to find Ctr+B action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keymap settings dialog has the **Find Actions by Shortcut** button to search by the shortcut, you just click on it and a field appears where you enter the shortcut:

[image: find action by shortcut]

[image: shortcut filter]

In this specific case you filter the actions by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and see the `Main menu` | `Navigate` | **Declaration** action.

Now you right click on the action name and add the new shortcut you want to use:

[image: mouse shortcut]

Double click in the dialog the appears to register the new shortcut:

[image: double click]

Press **OK** and now you can double click to go to the declaration in addition to the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut.

If you still need it, the same action [can be added to the toolbar or a menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html).